# JS: iPhone Address Book style sticky A-Z bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jquery-ui, webkit

I'm trying to build a little html5&JS app like iphone address book where when you scroll down the list, the B sticks to the top etc etc..

i'm having gard time with fixed position etc... using iScroll the same...
there is anything pre-cooked that i can use? a plugin of sort?

of course it has to work on iphone!

thanks

Comment: just wrote this fiddle for another answer, has css animation in it, although it's triggered by javascript http://jsfiddle.net/9J5Fg/3/ click on either of the toggle box-N buttons

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `UITableView` with plain style and implement sections. The effect you describe is exactly that and it works out of the box.

Comment: i'm talking about an app built in html5 not native